# Mystery blank space in aspx panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple for loop that adds items in an array to a Panel control.

Before the items are added to the panel I am outputting the information into a table via new Literal Control.

Anyhow whenever I add this line

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table border='1' cellspacing='10'>"));
```

I end up with

```
-----------HUGE white space-------------
x
x
x
x
x
------------------------Then my table follows below it.
blah1   blah 2
blah3   blah 4
```

As soon as I comment out the line above the white space goes away, but of course my table breaks as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `style="display:inline` ?

Comment: Use Chrome Dev Tools to inspect the white space.

Comment: Could you post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the source?

Comment: disable CSS on your browser to check there are no styles set for the table element.